# Codeigniter validating file upload and text input in one form

Tags: php, forms, validation, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form with text inputs and a file input. What is a proper way validate both input types using Codeigniter's validation library? I found some solutions but they don't work properly or seem like an overkill (creating new libraries or modifying CI system files).

In my view I'm using 1 multipart form and displaying both text validation error and upload errors.

Here is what I have so far in my Controller...

```
function create() //create new post
{           
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Entry', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_id', 'Category', 'trim|required|xss_clean|integer'); 

    //Text input fields
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('new_post');
    }       
    else
    {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/posts/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';               
            $config['max_size'] = '800'; //in KB

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            //File Upload
            if (! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $upload_error['upload_error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 

                $this->load->view('my_view', $upload_error);

                return FALSE;
            }

             //Add to database 
             $data = array (
               'user_id' => $this->tank_auth->get_user_id(),
               'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
               'content' => $this->input->post('content')
             );

             $this->Posts_model->create_post($data);

             $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Post_added!');
             redirect('posts');
    }       

}
```

I keep getting `You did not select a file to upload.` in my view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the name of your file input? do_upload() is expecting it by default to be 'userfile', however if you have something like `<input type="file" name="image"...` you will need to call `$this->upload->do_upload('image')`

You also need to make sure the form is set to multipart - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Thanks!! I did not set the name of my file input.

Answer (score 2):

You're using CodeIgniter's helpers correctly, this could be running more into a PHP problem then a CodeIgniter problem.

It looks like your file may be too big for your PHP configuration? PHP doesn't seem to be passing the file along to you. Create a `php_info()` file and see what `UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE` is set to?

Also, make sure you have the extension and mime type pair set in `application/config/mimes.php`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to upload allowed file size and type and still get the message. When I try to upload a file exceeding the max filesize I should get that error. Uploading works in my application when just processing type file.

Comment: Setting the extension/mime type pair fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

default codeigneter upload class is $this->upload->do_upload('field_name = userfile') , so you can set the name of field file you make or you use default codeigneter name field of file , if you want to change the name field for file type in your form , please check how codeigneter made setting for that class, actually is simple class and easy to use.., because that class need parameter name of file

Answer (score 0):

**Form field validation with file upload using codeigniter**

**Controller: Upload.php**

Note: create folder **uploads** at base level
Upload folder store file..

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        //$this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        //Text input fields
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('upload_form');
        }
        else
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1024';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

**Form:(upload.form.php)**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart();?>
Title: <input type="text" name="title" size="30" /><br/>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>

**upload_success.php**


<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart();?>
Title: <input type="text" name="title" size="30" /><br/>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```